# trying to get the selections of the boxes in my calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to finish off my calendar by making it where I click a box and it get highlighted. I'm having trouble doing so without making quite the amount of lines. if you could help that would be awesome! Thanks in advance!

Here's the code that I'm using to highlight the selected boxes:

```
if (x < 150 && x > 50){
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
            }else if (x < 250 && x > 150){
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillRect(150, 50, 100, 100);
            }else if (x < 350 && x > 250){
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillRect(250, 50, 100, 100);
            }else if (x < 450 && x > 350){
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillRect(350, 50, 100, 100);
            }else if (x < 550 && x > 450){
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillRect(450, 50, 100, 100);
            }else if (x < 650 && x > 550){
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillRect(550, 50, 100, 100);
            }else if (x < 750 && x > 650){
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillRect(650, 50, 100, 100);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting every field to the same color you can set the color once before the loop rather then within every if/if-else block. Instead of

```
if (x < 150 && x > 50){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 250 && x > 150){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fillRect(150, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 350 && x > 250){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fillRect(250, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 450 && x > 350){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fillRect(350, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 550 && x > 450){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fillRect(450, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 650 && x > 550){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fillRect(550, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 750 && x > 650){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fillRect(650, 50, 100, 100);
        }
```

You can get away with only setting the color once like this:

```
g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
if (x < 150 && x > 50){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 250 && x > 150){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.fillRect(150, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 350 && x > 250){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.fillRect(250, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 450 && x > 350){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.fillRect(350, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 550 && x > 450){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.fillRect(450, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 650 && x > 550){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.fillRect(550, 50, 100, 100);
        }else if (x < 750 && x > 650){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.fillRect(650, 50, 100, 100);
        }
```

Comment: yeah, that makes a lot of sense, I do wonder if there is an easier way of finding out the square I'm selecting though. Any ideas?